# Adjust child form's public variable from MDI parent form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, global-variables, mdichild, mdiparent

I have an MDI parent form that may open a child form called "Order". Order forms have a button that allows the user to print the order. The Order form has a print size variable defined at the beginning:

```
Public Class Order

Public psize As String 

    Private Sub button_order_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles process_order.Click
  ' Code to handle the order and then print, etc
```

Now the parent form has a `psize` variable as well, which is set to a default of "A4".
Only when someone clicks on one of the menu items on the Parent window's menu strip will this happen:

```
psize = "A6"
```

By default, whenever the parent window opens up a new Order form, I need it to set the child form's `psize` variable to its own `psize` value. Something like this:

```
    Dim f As Form
    f = New Order
    f.MdiParent = Me
    f.psize = Me.psize ' BUT THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
    f.Show()
```

I get the error that f.psize is not a member of the form.
I know that passing variables to and from the MDI parent and child is quite common but despite trying out a few options I saw here, it doesn't seem to be working. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: When I type "f", then I expect that "psize" should show up in the options that I can select and type f.psize... but I get the error that "psize is not a member of System...Windows.Forms". It works when I say Order.psize. But how can I assign its value in this current instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the property is not available is because you are using the wrong type for the variable.  The base `Form` type does not define that property.  Instead, your derived `Order` type does.  You could do something like this:

```
Dim f As Order
f = New Order
f.MdiParent = Me
f.psize = Me.psize
f.Show()
```

**UPDATE**

As you have said in comments below, what you really need to do is to be able to share a dynamic setting between all your forms so that you can change the setting at any time and have it affect all your forms that have already been displayed.  The best way to do that, would be to create a new class that stores all your shared settings, for instance:

```
Public Class Settings
    Public PaperSize As String = "A6"
End Class
```

As you can see, by doing so, you can easily centralize all your default settings in your settings class, which is an added benefit.  Then, you need to change the public property in your `Order` form to the new `Settings` type, for instance:

```
Public Class Order
    Inherits Form

    Public Settings As Settings
End Class
```

Then, you need to create your shared settings object in your MDI Parent form, and then pass it it to each of your `Order` forms as they are created:

```
Public Class MyParentForm
    Private _settings As New Settings()

    Private Sub ShowNewOrderForm()
        Dim f As New Order()
        f.MdiParent = Me
        f.Settings = _settings
        f.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangePaperSize(size As String)
        _settings.PaperSize = size
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, since the parent form and all the child `Order` forms share the same `Settings` object, and change made to that `Settings` object will be seen immediately by all the forms.

Comment: I tried this, it seems to go smooth because it doesn't show any errors. I put a msgbox on the Order form's load event to display the current psize. When I start up, it displays A4 as expected. But when I actually make a change in the MDI parent's psize, and then load a new Order form, its psize has no value... neither A4 nor A6, just blank! This is the code I'm using to actually change the parent's psize: `Me.psize = "A6"`... Very simple, but doesn't work!

Comment: Are you changing it after the Order form is already displayed?

Comment: Okay it worked but yes there's a problem with a currently open Order forms... I tried the following but again f.psize causes an error:
        'For Each f In Me.MdiChildren 
            If TypeOf (f) Is Order Then 
                  f.psize = Me.psize
            End If
        Next'
How can I dynamically re-assign the variable f to type "Order"?

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
Dim f As Form
```

to the actual implementation of your form:

```
Dim f As Order
```

or just the shortcut:

```
Dim f As New Order
```